# Is it nature of android summernote editor that page is scrolled down when I click editor area?

Tags: editor, wysiwyg, summernote

Whenever I click editor, page is scrolled down.
I think it is for positioning first line of editor area.
I just want nothing is changed on display whatever I do.

[before I click]
[image]

[after I click]
[image]

After I clicked(focused) it, Top buttons are hidden since input area is pulled up.

But I am not sure whether it is nature of summernote or nature of android webview.
Because IOS summernote doesn't scroll down much as android.
So I ask it to summernote expert. Is there any property or method for preventing this event? I totally need your help. 

Thank you.

Comment: Still I don't know how to solve it with javascript code, it is solved.
Android developer said it is solved when she modified some setting.
If there is someone who face this problem, go to android team and tell about this. Maybe they will solve it. In my case, turning off auto focus, adding scroll event and adding other trick events were not effective.